# Quick Launch selected item (which get bold font weight) is being wrongly determined

Tags: 2013, javascript, development, css, quick-launch

I have a team site inside my SharePoint on-premises farm 2013, inside the team site i added a custom list which contain 3 content types. 
Now when i create a new items inside the custom list, i will get different urls based on the content type,  as follow:-

```
/Lists/Management/NewForm.aspx?ContentTypeId=111&RootFolder=/Management/Lists/Management

/Lists/Management/NewForm.aspx?ContentTypeId=222&RootFolder=/Management/Lists/Management

/Lists/Management/NewForm.aspx?ContentTypeId=333&RootFolder=/Management/Lists/Management
```

Then to ease the process on end users, i add 3 links inside my  Quick Launch links, each link will have different `ContentTypeId`inside its URL. 
But the problem i am facing is that regardless of the link i click on , the last link will always get bold font weight, and this is confusing users .. For example, if they click to create an item which have `ContentTypeId=111`, the link which get selected will be the last one with 'ContentTypeId=333'.. so i am not sure if there is a way i can fix this layout issue?

Here is how my quick launch links look like, where the last link is being selected (url = `/Lists/Management/NewForm.aspx?ContentTypeId=333&RootFolder=/Management/Lists/Management`) although i clicked on the first link (url = `/Lists/Management/NewForm.aspx?ContentTypeId=111&RootFolder=/Management/Lists/Management`)..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While configuring the quick launch URLs add a new query string parameter at the end which has the text of the displayed link on quick launch. For example,

```
/Lists/Management/NewForm.aspx?ContentTypeId=111&RootFolder=/Management/Lists/Management&ct=New Order
```

Edit the NewForm.aspx page (or master page) and add the below javascript to the page. Remove the jquery reference if you already have one. Modify the code per your requirements

```
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var queryString = GetUrlKeyValue('ct');//SharePoint provides this method to get query string value
if(queryString != ''){
$("#sideNavBox span.menu-item-text").each(function(o,i){ 
    if(i.innerText === queryString){ 
$('#sideNavBox a.selected').removeClass('ms-bold');
        $('#sideNavBox a.ms-core-listMenu-selected').removeClass('ms-core-listMenu-selected'); //remove current selected link css
$(this).parent().parent().addClass('ms-bold');
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('ms-core-listMenu-selected'); //add the selected css to the correct link
        return;
    } 
});
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. now i tried your appraoch , but unfortunately it did not work, now i have a feeling that what ever i specify regarding this, will be override by sharepoint when the page load.. now i added the javascript at the end of my master page.. any idea?

Comment: I should have mentioned this earlier. I tried this code on a SharePoint 2016 on-prem site and it worked fine. You might want to look at the rendered html and css classes in dev tools on the site you have and change the code as needed.

Comment: have you tried modifying the NewForm.aspx page directly? Edit the page and add the code inside a script editor web part.

Comment: yes i tried adding the script to the new & edit forms,, but did not solve the issue. now i think the script will be able to retrieve the query string correctly + will be able to loop through the links and extract the outer text..  as i have added some alerts .. but seems those lines will not have any effect `$('#sideNavBox a.ms-core-listMenu-selected').removeClass('ms-core-listMenu-selected'); 
 $(this).parent().parent().addClass('ms-core-listMenu-selected');` or they are doing to be override..

Comment: ..now i tried using these `$('#sideNavBox a.selected').removeClass('ms-bold'); //remove current selected link css
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('ms-bold'); //add the selected css to the correct link` and seems everything worked well. but now i am not sure if manually adding a query parameter named `&ct=New Order` have any drawbacks ??

Comment: ..now on fire fox i am not sure why `i.outerText` will always be undefined.. while it is working well on chrome and on IE 11...

Comment: Nice! There are some drawbacks like, when someone modifies the display text of quick launch link, your code will stop working for the changed link. If that is something you are worried about, you need to change the javascript logic to use the content type id, but then everytime you add a content type you should be modifying your code. I suggest you use a content editor web part which links to a file in a SP library which has the js code.

Comment: try the innerText or textContent property instead of outerText...

Comment: Or better yet, use the content type id that's already in the link.  No need to add new query string parameter when you already have a unique value.  This will solve any issues that would come from changing display text on the link.

Comment: Also, you can use an attribute selector on href: `$("#sideNavBox a[href*='ContentTypeId=111']")` for the selected one, and `$("#sideNavBox a:not([href*='ContentTypeId=111'])")` to select all others.

Answer (score 5):

This is as per the design.

By default, links in quick launch does not accept query string parameters. when applying the 'selected' style it matches only the url component without parameters.

So all your links will be defaulted to "/Lists/Management/NewForm.aspx" when applying the style and last navigation item will be selected.

As a workaround you can put a script in your masterpage to remove current "selected" style and apply a new style by matching current url and quicklaunch url.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but can you please provide some useful links which can help me in writing a script allow me to remove the current selected style and apply a new style...