# How does SharePoint determine which link to bold in the left navigation in SP 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, navigation

In SP2013, I am using left nav, and customizing it in the site settings navigation. What I want is that, when I click a link on the nav, when I go to the page, the link in the nav will be bold. But I am getting inconsistent behavior. It either always bolds the last link or not bold any link.

Some of the links go to the same file, but it has different url params in the end of the url, if that matters.

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: What are your options for customization? Can you include JS/jQuery in master page?

Comment: try removing all links and adding them again.

Comment: There is no js/jquery. I meant customization in that I used the GUI in the navigation  in site settings, to add links.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design.

By default, links in quick launch does not accept query string parameters. when applying the 'selected' style it matches only the url component without parameters.

So all your links will be defaulted to "/Lists/Management/NewForm.aspx" when applying the style and last navigation item will be selected.

As a workaround you can put a script in your masterpage to remove current "selected" style and apply a new style by matching current url and quicklaunch url.

Similar issue post for your reference:

[Quick Launch selected item (which get bold font weight) is being wrongly determined](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/236799/quick-launch-selected-item-which-get-bold-font-weight-is-being-wrongly-determi)